# gnuplot postscript terminal not showing transparent symbols

Tags: gnuplot, postscript

Hopefully, this is a stupid question, and easy to fix. When I run this simple gnuplot script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot

set term png
set out "out.png"

plot "<jot -r -p 2 500 1 2" not w p pt 7 ps 4 lc rgb "#908DB6CD"

set term post eps enhanced color
set out "out.eps"

replot

exit
```

The png file looks like this:

[image: png output]

And the eps looks like this:

[image: eps output]

The `pdfcairo` terminal also gives me transparency. Any clues on how to make the eps files show transparency?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The eps terminal doesn't support transparency. If you punch in `help term [termname]` and it doesn't have a transparency option then that terminal doesn't support transparency

Comment: "help pdfcairo" doesn't say it has a transparency option. Does it really work?

Comment: Thanks @gavin-portwood, that is what I thought. @karl, yes, I could generate a pdf with pdfcairo with transparency. The workaround is then generate pdfs in gnuplot then do `pdftops -eps out.pdf` to get the eps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I should respond to my own question, so at least this becomes a case closed.

After some more digging, and from the comments I received, the bottom line is that the gnuplot `postscript` terminal does not handle transparency, while the `pdf` and `pdfcairo` terminals do.

The trick is to generate an .eps file from a .pdf using `pdftops`:

```
#!/bin/bash

gnuplot << GNU

set term pdf
set out "out.pdf"

plot "<jot -r -p 2 500 1 2" not w p pt 7 ps 4 lc rgb "#908DB6CD"

GNU

pdftops -eps out.pdf
```

All of my .eps files are generated to be incorporated to LaTeX documents. Then, I could just switch to PDFLaTeX and be over with it. However, at times I like to edit the .eps to tweak the bounding box and other things by hand or using awk/sed. Anyway, hope this is helpful.

Comment: You should be aware that the resulting EPS will not really have true transparency as in PostScript, there is no such thing. It's pretty likely that parts with transparency are actually rastered, i.e. you might loose the resolution independent vector qualities and end up with a (partial) bitmap.

Comment: You're right. I noticed that the resolution degraded a bit, but for the things I needed so far, it was not a big deal breaker (yet!). Thanks!